# Listen to wireless traffic with TCPDump

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop

I am trying to sniff traffic from a smartphone on the local WiFi network (in a legal way).
For that purpose I use the command TCPDump on a computer connected to the same wireless network.

I can sniff packets from iPhones, from a Galaxy phone with Android 5, but not from a Galaxy with Android 4.4.2.

With this device I can only sniff ICMP traffic, which is what is used for ping request. Instead of that I have nothing.

How can this be possible ? What can I do to sniff packets as I do with iPhones ? Does not Android used broadcasted messages for establishing a communication with an access point ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, I'd recommend the app [Intercepter-NG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=su.sniff.cepter). It's a bit tricky to use, and is known to generate false positives in anti-virus software, but it seems to be the only choice.

## How to use Intercepter-NG

As soon as the app starts up, select "Skip scanning" and, in the newly opened activity, choose the tab with the Wireshark icon. Press the Play/Start button to begin sniffing. The packets will be displayed on the screen, as well as saved to a PCAP file on the SD card.

Comment: Hi Arielle and thank you for your response. I am sorry I was unclear, I want to listen to traffic coming from a smartphone, not sniffing using the smartphone.
For that purpose I use a computer connected to the same WiFi access point and on the same local network than the smartphone.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid your question is off-topic for Android Enthusiasts. Try asking over at [Super User](http://superuser.com).